# Adjusting the alert dialog height to its content with material design theme?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I am using `AlertDialog` with `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert` theme to show a simple Yes/No alert notification with a message.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);

    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(text)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setResult(result);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
            .setIcon(icon)
            .show();
```

I have messages of different size, but the alert height doesn't accommodate shorter strings, resulting in a somewhat weird layout:

[image: Material design dialog]

If I remove the material design style from the alert, I get a perfectly normal alert with correct height:

[image: Alert without material design theme]

Is it possible to make this dialog automatically set its height to the message content with material design theme?

Comment: Are you using a custom view? Please provide more code, esp your creation of your Alert.

Comment: @FlorianHansen: No, I am not using any custom view here, just `seTitle()` and `setMessage()`. I edited my question to add the complete code for dialog creation.

Comment: I would suggest writing a style yourself with all the things you need and set it for your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Remove dialog title so upper blank space will be removed

Comment: This might work, but I really need the title and the icon.